# Greek syllabification library for Javascript

Tags: javascript, formal-languages

Does anyone know a good syllabification library or script for Greek written with Javascript? I tried to use Hyphenator.js but results were poor...

```
<script src="Hyphenator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="patterns/grc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var hyphenchar = '|';
    Hyphenator.config({hyphenchar:hyphenchar});
    var t = 'αποκαλυψις ιησου χριστου ην εδωκεν αυτω ο θεος δειξαι τοις δουλοις αυτου α δει γενεσθαι εν ταχει και εσημανεν αποστειλας δια του αγγελου αυτου τω δουλω αυτου ιωαννη'.split(" ").map(function(word){return Hyphenator.hyphenate(word, 'grc')});
    console.log(t);
</script>
```

Will output:

```
["απο|κα|λυ|ψις", "ιησου", "χρι|στου", "ην", "εδω|κεν", "αυτω", "ο", "θεος", "δει|ξαι", "τοις", "δου|λοις", "αυτου", "α", "δει", "γε|νε|σθαι", "εν", "ταχει", "και", "εση|μα|νεν", "απο|στει|λας", "δια", "του", "αγ|γε|λου", "αυτου", "τω", "δουλω", "αυτου", "ιω|αν|νη"]
```

Which evidently shows that hyphenation doesn't work perfectly for syllabification purposes. Maybe for hyphenation it is ok...

Later addition after comments:

I expected library to hyphenate "iesou" and "theos", but it turns out that there is a setting for minwordlength for hyphens. Setting it to 2, gives better results. Several sources say that automatic hyphenation / syllabification is not 100% exact due to many reasons. But this is enough for me at this point.

Comment: I don't know what Hyphenation.js is. Hyphenator.js? There's also Hypher. [Hyphenator.js or Hypher?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886258/hyphenator-js-or-hypher). It seems they are using state-of-the-art algorithms, normally used for typesetting in LaTeX. Did you select the language correctly? While I personally do not speak Greek, it would be helpful to include a code snippet (and text example) of what you did, what the poor results were, and what you expected instead.

Comment: Also note that asking for libraries is off topic for SO, voting to close the question.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know that. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: "Evidently"? It seems to work fine to me; but then again, as I said, I don't speak Ancient Greek with much proficiency. Let me repeat again: "include a code snippet (and text example) of what you did, what the poor results were, **and what you expected instead**". Did you expect it to hyphenate "iesou" and "theos"? In that case, take a look at the configuration setting `minwordlength`, which is by default `6` (which means words of 5 letters or less are left alone).

Comment: Brilliant @Amadan ! Now it works much better after changing minwordlength. For my luck, this tip became before the topic was closed. It happens quite often that when solving the problem, it turns out different questions and solutions occurs at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, short words are not hyphenated by default (as it makes no typographical sense). However, it can be forced:

```
Hyphenator.config({hyphenchar:hyphenchar, minwordlength:1});
```